# Grade 8-9 Maths Olympiad problem

Tags: inequality, contest-math

I was looking at my brother's Olympiad problems for grade $9$, and the problem was:

> $$\bigg(2x+\frac{1}{x}\bigg)\bigg(y+\frac{1}{y}\bigg)=4\sqrt{2}$$

The questions asks to find the integer part of $x-y$.

I know this is some manipulation problem algebraically to get the desired form for $(x-y)$, and tried rearranging algebraically in many ways but I am quite stuck at it.

Can anyone help me out or give me some clues?

Comment: Letting $u=x\sqrt 2$ this can be rewritten $$\left(u+\frac1u\right)\left(y+\frac1y\right)=4$$ Now use that $|v+1/v|\geq 2$ with equality when $v=\pm 1.$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We have by AM-GM,

$$y+\frac{1}{y} \ge 2$$

with equality for $$y=\dfrac{1}{y}$$

and

$$2x+\frac{1}{x} \ge 2\sqrt{2}$$

with equality for $$2x=\dfrac{1}{x}$$

Can you finish?

---

Note that

$$ y+\frac{1}{y} = (\sqrt{y} - \dfrac{1}{\sqrt{y}})^2 + 2$$

Similarly,

$$ 2x+\frac{1}{x} = (\sqrt{2x} - \dfrac{1}{\sqrt{x}})^2 + 2\sqrt{2}$$

And the minimum is obtained when variable part is zero.

---

For sake of completeness,

$$ \min (y+\frac{1}{y}) = 2$$ at $y=1$

$$ \min (2x+\frac{1}{x}) = 2\sqrt{2}$$ at $x=1/\sqrt{2}$

$$ \min (2x+\frac{1}{x})(y+\frac{1}{y}) = 4\sqrt{2}$$

So that $$x-y = 1/\sqrt{2} - 1 = -1 + 1/\sqrt{2}$$

Now you can figure out the integer part.

Comment: Someone who is 13 is supposed to know this?

Comment: For contest math, basic form of AM-GM should be familiar. Atleast, my students knew the first form. If not, this can be motivated by asking to form minimum sum by adding any number to its reciprocal.

Comment: I'll add explanation.

Comment: It seems the OP is asking for a more, first principles approach.

Comment: Wait so basically through those two inequalities, I get $x $and $y$ being $1$ as the minimum values which satisfies the two inequalities hence $x-y = 0$, is it this ?

Comment: @AuroraBorealis, almost but not quite. See updated answer.

Comment: Thank you I understand

Answer (score 2):

Using AMGM:

$$2x + \frac1x \ge 2\sqrt2, \ y + \frac1y \ge 2$$

AMGM has some strict equality conditions.